# How to change inflow velocity attributes randomly while animation

Tags: animation, physics, keyframes, fluid-simulation

Hey I'm new at blender physics. I want to make a fluid animation,  made some tutorials about fluid but need to change velocity attribute randomly during the animation. Thanks for you helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with **F-Curves**

1. Insert keyframe for inflow (press <kbd>I</kbd> hovering over the attribute).
2. Open Graph editor.
3. Add the [F-Curve Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/fcurves/fmodifiers.html): *Noise* (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>).

Or a little more complicated with a **Driver**

1. Add a [Driver](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/drivers/introduction.html#adding-removing) to the Attribute (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> hovering over the attribute ‣ Add Driver ‣ Manualy Create Later)
2. Open Graph editor
3. Go to Drivers Mode
4. Select the Curve of the Attribute you want to Animate
5. Go to Drivers Tab in Toolshelf
6. Set the Driver to `noise.random()`